# MySQL Trigger AFTER UPDATE IF ELSE insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to make a trigger **insert into** a table after the update of the `checkedOutBy` in the *equip* table.

It gave me an `Error 1064` at lines 7, 10 and others as I have randomly changed things hoping that somehow it may just magically work.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER moveToHistory AFTER UPDATE ON equip
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.checkedOutBy <> Old.checkedOutBy
BEGIN

IF OLD.checkedOutBy IS NOT NULL AND NEW.checkedOutBy IS NULL THEN
     INSERT INTO equipmentHistory(assetId, operation, createdBy, creationDate)
     VALUES(new.assetId, 'CheckIn', eid, Date(sysdate()))
     NEW.status = 'CheckedIn';
ELSE IF OLD.checkedOutBy IS NULL AND NEW.checkedOutBy IS NOT NULL THEN
     INSERT INTO equipmentHistory(assetId, operation, createdBy, creationDate)
     VALUES(new.assetId, 'Checkout', eid, Date(sysdate()))
     NEW.status = 'CheckedOut';
END IF
END
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Randomly changing things and hoping for magic is almost never a good idea. Having said that, help us help you - can you please post your table's DDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the trigger with proper syntax for `if - elseif`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER moveToHistory AFTER UPDATE ON equip
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.checkedOutBy <> Old.checkedOutBy then
   IF OLD.checkedOutBy IS NOT NULL AND NEW.checkedOutBy IS NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO equipmentHistory(assetId, operation, createdBy, creationDate)
      VALUES(new.assetId, 'CheckIn', eid, curdate());
   ELSEIF OLD.checkedOutBy IS NULL AND NEW.checkedOutBy IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO equipmentHistory(assetId, operation, createdBy, creationDate)
       VALUES(new.assetId, 'Checkout', eid, curdate());
   END IF;
END IF ;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Also note that I have removed `NEW.status = 'CheckedIn';` and `NEW.status = 'CheckedOut';` , these does not make sense when you try to set using a `after update` trigger

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I totally spaced it about the curdate() also. Fantastic. Is there anything like visual studio which I can help make sure I don't make silly mistakes like that? Again thank you.

Comment: Well unfortunately there is no such tool that I am aware of. A good way would be try on mysql cli and let mistake happens and from there only you got to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER moveToHistory AFTER UPDATE ON equip
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.checkedOutBy != Old.checkedOutBy
BEGIN

IF OLD.checkedOutBy IS NOT NULL AND NEW.checkedOutBy IS NULL THEN
     INSERT INTO equipmentHistory(assetId, operation, createdBy,creationDate)
     VALUES(new.assetId, 'CheckIn', eid, Date(sysdate()))
 NEW.status = 'CheckedIn';
ELSE IF OLD.checkedOutBy IS NULL AND NEW.checkedOutBy IS NOT NULL THEN
 INSERT INTO equipmentHistory(assetId, operation, createdBy, creationDate)
 VALUES(new.assetId, 'Checkout', eid, Date(sysdate()))
 NEW.status = 'CheckedOut';
END IF
END
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: How can a simple != instead of <> would work? It's better if you take a fully look of the whole trigger instead of randomly dropping an answer, just saying.